# How to access a VCL-Control from another PHP script?

Tags: php, delphi4php

I have a Treeview on my main page. This makes the control a member of main page class.

How can I access this control from another PHP script?

A "require_once" with the main page file doesn't work, that re-creates the main page when the other script is called because of the commands at the bottom of each VCL-page's source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution to this, so a major restructuring of the software could prevent the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your tree class and the main page.

```
require_once("tree.class.php");
```

Comment: How can I do this? If I remove the Treeview from the main page, it will not be accessible in the IDE anymore, meaning I cannot modify it in the IDE (Object inspector etc.).
Could you give me an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you access the treeview from another script? It seems like you have to do something that requires user action. Maybe you should go after some javascript.